# STI polymorphic has_many uses wrong type value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have the following STI models, they have a polymorphic association, whose query is being wrongly constructed

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end

class OneProduct < Product
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable
end
```

In a rails console, when I do

```sh
> OneProduct.last.icon_images
```

The query being fired is

```sql
SELECT  * FROM images WHERE imageable_id = id AND imageable_type = 'Product'
```

I was expecting:

```sql
SELECT * from images WHERE imageable_id = id AND imageable_type = 'OneProduct'
```

Am I expecting something wrong?

Side Info: database is postgres.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Rails docs:

> Using polymorphic associations in combination with single table inheritance (STI) is a little tricky. In order for the associations to work as expected, ensure that you store the base model for the STI models in the type column of the polymorphic association. To continue with the asset example above, suppose there are guest posts and member posts that use the posts table for STI. In this case, there must be a type column in the posts table.
>
> **Note:** The `attachable_type= method` is being called when assigning an
>   attachable. The `class_name` of the attachable is passed as a `String`.
>
> ```
> class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base   
>   belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
>
>   def attachable_type=(class_name)
>      super(class_name.constantize.base_class.to_s)   
>   end 
> end
>
> class Post < ActiveRecord::Base   
>   # because we store "Post" in attachable_type now dependent: :destroy will work   
>   has_many :assets,as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy 
> end
>
> class GuestPost < Post end
>
> class MemberPost < Post end
> ```

**Source:** https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Polymorphic+Associations

So it says that instead of storing the `imageable_type = OneProduct` you need to store it as `Product` only and you can add a `type` column in the `Product` table. But that depends completely on what you need from the `OneProduct` model, if a `default_scope` on that model will make it work for you without adding the `type` column then don't add it on the `Product` table and if that doesn't work then you can add the column and then add the `default_scope` to fetch `products.type = OneProduct` when querying on `OneProduct` model.

Comment: thanks for the info. Makes sense. I already have a `type` column on `Product` b/c that table is STI enabled. So adding a default scope should solve my needs